# Removing the default Help command in Cogs and Replacing a new custom one. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have searched a lot of StackOverflow answers and youtube videos, but I am very confused now.

Is there any way to remove the default help command and replace it with a custom one in **COGS**?

Here is my code by the way.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Help(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Help is Ready')

    
#help cmd

    @commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    async def help(self, ctx):
        em1 = discord.Embed(title = 'Help',
                        description = 'Commands to get you started!')

        em1.add_field(name='Fun', value = 'Commands that everyone can use for fun!', inline = False)

        em1.add_field(name = 'Moderation', value = 'Moderation commands to manage your server!', inline = False)

        em1.add_field(name = 'Math', value ='Math commands to help you calculate stuff.')

    @help.command(aliases = ['Fun'])
    async def fun(self, ctx):
        fun_em = discord.Embed(title = 'Fun Commands', colour = discord.Colour.dark_teal())

        fun_em.add_field(name = 'slap', value = 'Slap someone if you are angry!\n\nUsage: -slap <Mention the user you want to Slap>', inline = False)

        fun_em.add_field(name = '8ball', value = 'A random answer to your Question.\n\nUsage: -8ball <Your Question here.>', inline = False)

        await ctx.send(embed=fun_em)


    
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Help(bot))
```

I tried doing `bot.remove_command('help')` in my main.py but that just completely removes the help command. I want to replace it with a new one.

Please explain me a bit thoroughly as I am new to discord.py.

Comment: I have already made the custom help command as you can see in the code.

I just want to know how to replace it.

Comment: Not exactly. As I mentioned earlier, if I just remove it like that, then the help command defined in this cog does not work

Comment: Saying "does not work" it's vague and not really helpful to us, what do you mean by that?

Comment: The command is just removed. There is no error in the terminal. When i execute the commmand in discord, no messagge is sent by the bot

Comment: Because you're not sending a message inside the command... Take a look at it, I don't see any `ctx.send` anywhere there

Comment: I did `bot.remove_command('help')` but it completely removes it.

Comment: That might be the case. Let me check

Comment: **Łukasz Kwieciński** in other words: You defined `em1` but are not sending it with `await ctx.send(embed=em1)`

Comment: Ok its working. It was my mistake of not sending the embed after defining it. Sorry. Silly Mistakes. Thanks for correcting me